# Título de relatorio no IReport

Tags: java

Nos relatórios que crio no IReport, a área de título(title) só sai na primeira página e a área page header(cabeçalho) sai em todas as páginas.

Como posso fazer o title sair em todas as páginas e o page header sair somente na primeira página?

Na opção "Print When Expression" do Page Header fiz assim:

`$V{PAGE_NUMBER} == 1`

Deu certo, agora só exibe na primeira página.

Na opção "Print When Expression" do Title fiz assim:

`$V{PAGE_NUMBER} >= 1`

Só que o title continua exibindo só na primeira página...

Answer (score 0):

A band de título (Title) realmente só é exibida uma vez no relatório. Você pode deixar a band Title vazia e colocar o título na band do cabeçalho (Page Header).

Comment: No titulo tenho coisas que quero que sempre apareça, e no header tem coisa que quero que apareça somente na primeira página, já configurei o header para aparecer só na primeira página, se eu colocar o titulo no header vai aparecer somente na primeira página.

Mas ai você pode me falar para mim tirar a configuração do header para aparecer em todas as paginas e colocar o titulo no header, mas se eu fizer isso o titulo que está no header irá sim aparecer em todas as páginas, mas o restante do conteúdo do header que quero que apareça somente na primeira página, também irá aparecer em todas.